# How to implement custom font-face to angular 15 typography to use globally

Tags: sass, typography, angular15

I have new angular 15 project and I would like to implement custom font-face as my typography but I can't make it work.

```
  my fonts folder:
  assets/fonts/Barlow-Medium.woff
              /typografy.scss

  typography.scss
 @font-face {
   font-family: 'Barlow'
   src: url(./Barlow-Medium.woff) format('woff')
  }
```

then in my styles.scss I have this:

```
     @import '../fonts/typography.scss'

     $font-family: 'Barlow';

     $my-app-primary: mat.define-palette($primary);

     $my-app-accent: mat.define-palette($primary);

     $my-app-warn: mat.define-palette($primary);



     $my-typography: mat.define-legacy-typography-config(

      $headline: mat.define-typography-level($font-family), /*<h1>*/

      $title: mat.define-typography-level(18px, 18px, 600, Barlow),/*<h2>*/                          

      );



      $my-app-theme: mat.define-light-theme((color: (

          primary: $my-app-primary,

          accent: $my-app-accent,

          warn: $my-app-warn,

          typography: $my-typography,

       ),
      ));



     @include mat.all-component-themes($my-app-theme);
```

in my index.html I am making sure to define mat-typology class on higest level

```
   index.html
<body class="mat-typography">
 <app-root></app-root> 
 </body>
```

and finally in my component template:

```
  <h1>My title</h1> // here I would expect my font to apply but it's not
```